# Is it possible to get data from div inside div with overflow:hidden with python's requests?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm scraping website and got stuck with reaching data stored in div with `overflow:hidden` CSS tag.

I can reach the div with `overflow:hidden` (`variants__container-items`), but it responds with empty list although it has a few div's inside.

Also, beautiful soup should find those divs (e.g. `variant__available-qty`, `variant__item`) directly, but it doesn't.

```
<div class="variants__container-items">
    <div id="variant__70259" class="variants__container-item">
        <div class="variant__price">
            <div class="price">69.24&nbsp;zł</div>
        </div>
        <div class="variant__item">
            <div class="variant__attributes">36-39 </div>
            <div class="variant__sku">610306139887</div>
        </div>
        <div class="variant__qty">
            <form method="post" action="https://some_link_here">
                (...)
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="variant__available-qty">6</div>
    </div>
(...)
```

BeautifulSoup can find div `variants__container-items`, but it is an empty list (because it's CSS tag is `overflow: hidden`.

I would like to reach data in div `variant__70259` (especially in div `variant__available-qty`, which returns 6 in given example).

I cannot share URL, because it needs login to see the data.

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Can you share url?

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add content then you can't do this with requests + BS but you need `Selenium` to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: it is much easier when you add url to this page (PL: będzie łatwiej jeśli podasz URL do tej strony)

Comment: if page doesn't use JavaScript and all content is already in HTML then you can get it and `overflow:hidden` has nothing to do with this - you are looking in pure HTML which doesn't use `CSS`

Comment: I cannot share URL, because it needs login to see the data. The page uses JavaScript, I have to use selenium to login.
So I guess selenium is the only answer in this case? 
I also asked question to this issue with xml approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58183799/getting-data-from-broken-xml-in-python