# Getting data from broken xml in Python

Tags: python, json, xml, python-requests, lxml

I would like to get data from xml, but it structure seems to be broken.

I have this example URL: `https://b2b.snapoutdoor.pl/rest/V1/extendvariantstocart/73478`
Which is xml with data about the product.

```
import requests
import json
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from pprint import pprint

response = requests.get(
    "https://b2b.snapoutdoor.pl/rest/V1/extendvariantstocart/86559",
    headers={"Accept": "application/xml"},
)

node = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)

data = json.loads(node.text)
```

this returns dict with four keys:

```
{'jsonChildsConfig': '{"70259":{"id":"70259","name":"Ski Ultra Merino E - '
                     'black\\/orange","sku":"610306139887","availableQty":6,"regularPrice":69.2367,"finalPrice":69.2367,"promo":false,"discount":0,"bestDiscount":false,"addToCartUrl":"https:\\/\\/b2b.snapoutdoor.pl\\/checkout\\/cart\\/add\\/uenc\\/aHR0cHM6Ly9iMmIuc25hcG91dGRvb3IucGwvcmVzdC9WMS9leHRlbmR2YXJpYW50c3RvY2FydC84NjU1OQ%2C%2C\\/product\\/86559\\/","formKey":"7OWS6VbWucoSg2zg","superAttributes":"36-39 '
                     '","salable":true},"70260":{"id":"70260","name":"Ski '
                     'Ultra Merino E - '
                     'black\\/orange","sku":"610306139894","availableQty":7,"regularPrice":69.2367,"finalPrice":69.2367,"promo":false,"discount":0,"bestDiscount":false,"addToCartUrl":"https:\\/\\/b2b.snapoutdoor.pl\\/checkout\\/cart\\/add\\/uenc\\/aHR0cHM6Ly9iMmIuc25hcG91dGRvb3IucGwvcmVzdC9WMS9leHRlbmR2YXJpYW50c3RvY2FydC84NjU1OQ%2C%2C\\/product\\/86559\\/","formKey":"7OWS6VbWucoSg2zg","superAttributes":"40-43 '
                     '","salable":true},"70261":{"id":"70261","name":"Ski '
                     'Ultra Merino E - '
                     'black\\/orange","sku":"610306139900","availableQty":6,"regularPrice":69.2367,"finalPrice":69.2367,"promo":false,"discount":0,"bestDiscount":false,"addToCartUrl":"https:\\/\\/b2b.snapoutdoor.pl\\/checkout\\/cart\\/add\\/uenc\\/aHR0cHM6Ly9iMmIuc25hcG91dGRvb3IucGwvcmVzdC9WMS9leHRlbmR2YXJpYW50c3RvY2FydC84NjU1OQ%2C%2C\\/product\\/86559\\/","formKey":"7OWS6VbWucoSg2zg","superAttributes":"44-47 '
                     '","salable":true},"99060":{"id":"99060","name":"Ski '
                     'Ultra Merino E - '
                     'black\\/orange","sku":"610306139917","availableQty":3,"regularPrice":69.24,"finalPrice":69.24,"promo":false,"discount":0,"bestDiscount":false,"addToCartUrl":"https:\\/\\/b2b.snapoutdoor.pl\\/checkout\\/cart\\/add\\/uenc\\/aHR0cHM6Ly9iMmIuc25hcG91dGRvb3IucGwvcmVzdC9WMS9leHRlbmR2YXJpYW50c3RvY2FydC84NjU1OQ%2C%2C\\/product\\/86559\\/","formKey":"7OWS6VbWucoSg2zg","superAttributes":"48+ '
                     '","salable":true}}',
 'jsonConfig': 'some data',
 'jsonDefaultPlaceholder': 'https://b2b.snapoutdoor.pl/pub/media/catalog/product/placeholder/',
 'jsonSwatchConfig': 'some data'
}
```

I'm interested with values of `jsonChildsConfig`, but when trying to reach keys inside it, I got 
`TypeError: string indices must be integers` because the value for `jsonChildsConfig` is a string.

I would like to get all sku and stock values from `sku` and `availableQty` but theirs type is string and it is not possible to get it through

`data['jsonChildsConfig']['70259']['sku']`

or

`data['jsonChildsConfig']['70259']['availableQty']`.

I also tried to convert this string to json byt `json.loads()` but it didn't work.

Could you please help me with it?

Comment: `json.loads(d['jsonChildsConfig'])` worked for me given the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your dictionary you need to apply `json.loads` to all the values ​​of your dictionary, excluding `'jsonDefaultPlaceholder'` which is not in json format:

```
del data['jsonDefaultPlaceholder']
new_data = {k: json.loads(v) for k, v in data.items() if v}
new_data['jsonChildsConfig']['70259']['sku']

#output: '610306139887'
```

or if you want to convert the keys that interest you into integer values:

```
del data['jsonDefaultPlaceholder']
new_data2 = {k: {(int(key) if key.isdigit() else key): val for key,val in json.loads(v).items()} for k, v in data.items() if v}
new_data2['jsonChildsConfig'][70259]['sku']

# output: '610306139887'
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting the value of data['jsonChildsConfig'] to dict using json.loads should work

```
>>> childConfigDetails = json.loads(data['jsonChildsConfig'])
>>> childConfigDetails['70259']['sku']
'610306139887'
```